# Is it good idea to use database connection directly through python CGI script?

Tags: python, cgi

Is it a good idea to use database connection directly from python CGI Script, which will be called from our client side?

If it is then, every time our server side script is called it will try to connect to database.
So basically if we have 100,000 clients trying to call our server script it will connect to that database and do its job(Which may be similar for all clients)?

If it's not then how should we tackle such situations?

Thanks

Comment: The real question is "is it a good idea to use CGI in 2017?", and the answer is "no".

Comment: @jordanm
Probably not, but its good practice to learn the core technology first then to let other tools handle it every time for us.